# Change CSS class on an element using JavaScript without FOUC

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I found a HTML5 way of changing a class of an element using JavaScript.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="bootstrap-container" class="container-fluid fill-height">
   <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)');
if (mql.matches) {
    var containerElement = document.querySelector('#bootstrap-container');
    if (containerElement.classList.contains('container-fluid')) {
        containerElement.classList.remove('container-fluid');
        containerElement.classList.add('container');
    }
}
```

This works fine except there is a noticeable [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) when loading/refreshing the page.

How can I make the [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) go away?

Comment: I expect any styling that relies on JS will have the potential for a FOUC, this looks like something you could potentially do with just a CSS media query, which is generally less prone to creating a FOUC.

Comment: Agreed, but in this case the built-in container class in bootstrap contains a lot of styles which would have to be overriden in a media-query block in the stylesheet and that is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: @DBS generally speaking you're right, but there are some (valid) cases/logic, which can't be covered by media queries.

Answer (score 1):

When the browser parses your HTML-File, he will execute your JavaScript (either inline or by reference `<script src="script.js">`) exactly where he found it. Therefore you have 2 possibilities to avoid the mentioned FOUC.

1. You execute the JavaScript earlier (e.g. as inline javascript right below the element you manipulate the class). It might be a good idea to set only 1 "media query class" (e.g. on the `body`-tag) and place your corresponding script right below
2. You hide the content until your JavaScript has been executed. E.g. you could do something like this

HTML

```
<body class="loading">
 ...
</body>
```

CSS

```
body.loading {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)');
if (mql.matches) {
    var containerElement = document.querySelector('#bootstrap-container');
    if (containerElement.classList.contains('container-fluid')) {
        containerElement.classList.remove('container-fluid');
        containerElement.classList.add('container');
    }
}

document.body.classList.remove("loading")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a partial view and using bootstraps responsive utility classes hidden-xs, hidden-sm and so on.